# How to analyze a dichotomous outcome with 50% missing data?

Tags: multiple-regression, missing-data, nonlinear-regression, structural-equation-modeling, multiple-imputation

I am researching predictors of dropout from a training program. I want so to see if personality traits add incremental variance above well-established predictors like age, fitness, and education. So, in the end, I want to do a hierarchical logistic regression and compare the difference in *R<sup>2</sup>*. The (simplified) full model to predict dropout will look something like this:

```
dropout = age + education type + fitness level + personality trait A … + personality trait J
```

I do not expect any interactions. Dropout is a dichotomous variable (yes/no). Education type is a categorical variable, fitness level ordinal, the personality traits are continuous and normally distributed.

I measured potential predictors at T1 (age, fitness, education, personality traits) and the outcome “dropout” a few months later at T2. While there is less than 1% missing data for the predictors in T1, about 50% of the outcome in T2 is missing. In other words, the questionnaire in T1 was answered by 1000 persons, and my follow-up call in T2 (whether people still do the training) by 500. Out of these 500, 460 people kept up the training and 40 people dropped out. I am not sure how I should handle the focal analysis of my question (are personality traits useful predictors) and this amount of missing data. I am usually working with R and consider two options:

**Option 1:** I consider using multiple imputation to fill in the missing data (R package MICE). The data suggests a MAR mechanism, where the missingness depends on the personality of the participants (undisciplined people fill out T2 significantly less). I could use this information to tailor the imputations and do a sensitivity analysis to estimate what effect an alternative NMAR mechanism would have. Then I could use a logistic regression model to answer my main question, namely which variables from T1 best predict dropout.

**Option 2:** I think I also could build a structural equation model to answer my question and use FIML to handle missing data (R package lavaan). This option is attractive because I will build SEMs anyway to analyze personality variables for a different research question. SEM also considers measurement errors; I think those would go unnoticed in option 1. However, I am not sure if SEM and ML can handle this non-normal outcome with 50% missing data. Also, I am used to interpreting the effect of predictors in terms of *R<sup>2</sup>* and ORs, would a similar quantification be available in a structural equation model?

Which option would you recommend to me and why?

To clarify: At T2 I just measured the outcome (dropout yes/no), none of the other variables. The amount of missing data is high because, contrary to T1, the participants were contacted via phone or email at home. In T1, everyone was gathered in a classroom setting and probably felt more committed. This was not possible to do at T2.

Comment: What's in the questionnaire and why and why are you giving it twice?

Comment: Reading the currently available answer it seems it is not 100% clear what data were actually collected at T2 and what kind of data are missing. My understanding is that *only* outcomes, i.e., dropout of not, are missing, but it seems others have a different interpretation, and I can kind of see why. Please be more explicit about this.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I used the questionnaire at T1, not at T2. It includes questions about personality (BFI-2) and demographic variables. At T2, my only question for the participants was "Are you still in the training program?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your description implies that you committed the mortal sin of not pre-specifying the final model in the sense that you tried different models in a way not unlike stepwise variable selection does (mislabeling this as hierarchical modeling).  This will ruin all aspects of inference, especially resulting in a falsely small $\hat{\sigma}$.  More to your question, this is not best called a missing data problem but is a problem with non-random non-response.  Surveys that examine changes over time (such as pre-post analysis) must ensure that all people included at T1 also respond at T2 otherwise results can have a major bias.

You might do a conditional analysis of persons who had data in both periods.  But this is *very* conditional.

If you treat this as a missing data problem, multiple imputation will not add much efficiency over doing a complete case analysis when the main variable missing is the dependent variable.

Think hard about whether this study design is adequate to answer your main questions of interest.  It may not be.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed it seems that this design is suboptimal. However, I don't fully understand your first part of the answer. Based on previous research and literature, I did pre-specify the model (as it is in the gray text box) and wanted to test that in my analysis. I did not test any other model to explain dropout so far. I just checked correlations between missingness and predictors until now.

Comment: I think if you read Frank's answer as "you did not pre-specify your analysis" rather than "your model" you might grasp his meaning better. But it would bring you dividends to come around to Frank's thinking. You seem to under the illusion that the only modelling you have done/will do is in the grey box. But the Q you asked here is really "how should I model non-random non-response"! In other words, there are still *researcher degrees of freedom* in play here, which pre-specifying your analysis (including how to deal with the situation you just found yourself in) would have avoided.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to predict what happens at T2 from data at T1, you could run a three classes model with "dropout", "no dropout", and "T2 missing" as the classes.

Note that data with missing outcome will not help you to predict the outcome from the predictors. Imputing the outcome is pointless, as this doesn't increase the amount of information of how the predictors work on the outcome. "The data suggests a MAR mechanism" - there is no way to distinguish MAR from MNAR based on the data.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I was unsure about if I can gain additional information at all by imputing the outcome. I am glad you have addressed this point. In addition, I know I can't really distinguish MAR from NMAR. My plan was to do a sensitivity analysis and see how much a NMAR model would differ from my MAR model and results. I have added this to my problem description.

Answer (score 7):

First, I don't see how variables at time 2 can be sensibly used to predict dropout at time 2. So, I don't think you need to even worry about the missing data. I'm not sure why you collected it. You seem to know who dropped out, even if they have missing data at time 2, since you refer to that information.

Second, I agree with Frank Harrell about the perils of doing variable selection the way you seem to be planning to do it. At a minimum, if you are planning this, then do a train and test set -- that is, divide the data in two and build your model on the training set, then report the results from running the same model on the test set.

Third, right now, from your description, I see no need for SEM.  You seem to have a relatively straightforward logistic regression problem. But maybe there are things you haven't said that make SEM worthwhile. In general, I am not a big fan of SEM. Of course it *can* be useful when done well, but it's very easy to go wrong, and very easy to cheat by adjusting things endlessly until they work. Do you have some sort of latent variable?

Fourth, be sure to check for collinearity among the 10 personality traits. These traits are usually related to each other and can cause problems.

Finally, I don't know why you are ruling out interactions.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback about the training and test set. I could model my personality variables as latent variables, each one based on three observed values (three questions in the questionnaire). As for the interactions, I ruled them out because such effects have not been found in previous research about similar trainings and I thought a simpler model makes more sense. I just could not find a theoretical justification for an interaction.